# Wrong answer with Addition

Tags: java, oop, object

```
public class Container {
    private int value;
    public Container(int value){
        this.value=value;
    }
    public int getValue(){
        return this.value;
    }
    public int sum(Container c){
        return this.value+c.getValue();
    }
    public void main(){
        Container c1=new Container(1);
        Container c2=new Container(2);
        System.out.println("sum: " + c1.getValue()+c2.getValue());
        System.out.println("sum: " + c1.sum(c2));
    }
}
```

when I am running this code I am getting the following results:

```
sum: 12
sum: 3
```

expected is:

```
sum: 3
sum: 3
```

Does anyone know why I am getting these results?

Comment: Your first sum is not a sum on integer, but a string concatenation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you use the `+` operator with a `String` it treats it as concatenation, not addition, and Java evaluates operations from left to right, so `"sum: " + c1.getValue()+c2.getValue()` is being evaluated as

```
"sum: " + 1 + 2
"sum: 1" + 2
"sum: 12"
```

If you want the integer addition to happen first, you need to add parentheses:

```
System.out.println("sum: " + (c1.getValue() + c2.getValue()));
```

Comment: Another option would be to calculate the numeric value separately, and store that in an `int` variable: `int sum = c1.getValue() + c2.getValue();` then on the next line, print it out: `System.out.println("sum: " + sum);`. Breaking things up like that is nice when using a debugger.